# Injecting an ID in my tr tag of my table with knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

Before using knockout, I was injecting an id in my tr of my table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="@item.id">
        ....
```

Then @item.id was replaced (server side)

Now I use knockout and I don't know how to inject my 'id' in my < tr > tag.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the attr binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'attr' binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': id }">
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VKP4J/